# Sagittarius star cloud?

Tags: galaxy, photography

I was using SkySafari with my phone, but the compass didn't quite work.
So as I knew where the cardinal points were, I think I have shot the Sagittarius star cloud, at least a part of it.

Can you guys tell me if I am wrong?

[image]

It was the 5th of July at 00:10 local time. I was at N 45.61°, E 7.35°.

Comment: http://imgur.com/VbC2kAR

Comment: Without further context it is impossible to stay where you're pointing at. This looks like it is part of the Milky May, yes, and maybe pointing vaguely towards Sg, but other than that I cannot see anthing clearly distinguishable. Also I don't think 'star cloud' is a defined term. So people (and me) might not know what you mean.

Comment: There are tools which can calculate the sky position from the stars visible in the image. I tried with the image in your question, but unfortunately it failed (http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/2923225#original) If you have a higher resolution version of the image, you could try again.

Answer (score 7):

The image scale is a bit small, but I can see the constellation of Lyra just above center. The bright star Deneb (in the constellation of Cygnus) is left of center, and the star Altair (in the constellation of Aquila) is at the bottom (just right of center). Thus, your photo does not include Sagittarius. Sagittarius is off to the bottom right. The Scutum star cloud is the bright patch toward the right corner.

[image]

It would be helpful if you include the time of the photograph and location (latitude and longitude).

Comment: It was the 5th of July  at 00:10. I was here 45,6073126, 7,3533987

Comment: I think you've nailed it. I've added a picture based on your identification of stars

Answer (score -2):

You've definitely got the Milky Way here. The galactic centre in Sagittarius is slightly thickened and noticeably brighter than the rest of the Milky way, so I think you might have got it in the bottom right hand corner of your photograph.